# How do some controllers detect and control devices with different pinouts?

Tags: circuit-design, soldering, control-system

There are controller circuits capable of identifying and powering a variety of devices regardless of different pin configurations. As an example, a few soldering stations, such as the [Unisolder](https://github.com/sparkybg/UniSolder-5.2/blob/main/schematics/sensor.pdf), work with a variety of soldering irons with the heater and thermal sensors on different pins. Some stations can even detect a PTC or K-Type Thermocouple sensor and whether it's separate or wired in series with the heater circuit.

How can this be done reliably and without damaging the controller or the device? Supplying 24V to determine the heater pin, for instance, might damage a thermal sensor if it's on the pin under test. Moreover, testing for the presence of a thermal sensor requires a voltage or resistance reference which isn't reliable, especially if the iron is still hot from being used a shortly before plugging it in. Perhaps, I'm over analyzing it and the controller merely tests for an identifier present on the device?

Comment: Add in a link to the datasheet in your question so we can search for clues.

Comment: @Transistor  I've included the schematic of the Unisolder, but a general answer would suffice.

Comment: A PTC vs a thermocouple is easy--just measure the resistance. A thermocouple will have very low resistance, a PTC will have a larger one. Other things will have other methods; how you distinguish things depends on what the things are, generally.

Comment: @Hearth, What if the temperature is already high?  What's you're reference?

Comment: @user148298 If the temperature is high, the PTC thermistor will have an even higher resistance and the thermocouple will still have very low resistance; I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Hearth  Hmmm. OK. Wouldn't heater and PTC have similar resistance? If the thermocouple is in series with the heater, then aren't you're measuring the resistance of the heater too?

Comment: How would you expect temperature sensing to work if the thermocouple is in series with the heater?

Comment: Looking at the top page of that GitHub project, I see a long list showing how to connect various soldering irons to the controller - you can't just blindly plug any iron into the controller, you must make an adaptor cable to get the right thiings on the correct pins.